# Bootstrap tabs not changing content

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to integrate bootstrap tabs in one of our pages.
I've copied the example from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior but the tabs are not working correctly (they show up correctly but when I click on a tab, nothing happens).

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">contact</div>
</div>
```

Both bootstrap and jQuery are installed:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.6.1",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
```

and bundled correctly (has other pages use them as well).

What could be the reason that the content isn't changing?
Do I have to add JS code manually?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
I've tried registering the click events for each tab.
When clicking on a tab, it console logs the corresponding message but does not show the correct content...

```
$(document).on('click', '#home-tab', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('home clicked')
    $('#myTab a[href="#home"]').tab('show')
})

$(document).on('click', '#profile-tab', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('profile clicked')
    $('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show')
})

$(document).on('click', '#contact-tab', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('contact clicked')
    $('#myTab a[href="#contact"]').tab('show')
})
```

Comment: Did you include Bottstrap's JS library on the page?

Comment: @punund yes bootstrap is bundled into a vendor.js via webpack and the vendor.js is loaded

Comment: @xeraphim do you get some sort of error in the console? It seems like you've set it up correctly in terms of the HTML -- I'm guessing something is conflicting which is causing an error when you try change tabs

Comment: @Simp4Code unfortunately no feedback from the console :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the official Bootstrap guide, it looks like you need to add the Javascript code manually:

> Enable tabbable tabs via JavaScript (each tab needs to be activated individually):

```js
$('#myTab a').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

> You can activate individual tabs in several ways:

```js
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
$('#myTab li:first-child a').tab('show') // Select first tab
$('#myTab li:last-child a').tab('show') // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:nth-child(3) a').tab('show') // Select third tab
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this info!
I've registered the click events for all the tabs like show in the edit of the original post. The console logs are printed correctly but the content of the tabs are not changed...

Comment: Try to use  `$('#myTabContent a[href="#contact"]').tab('show')` instead of `$('#myTab a[href="#contact"]').tab('show')`

Comment: it worked with `$('#myTabContent div[id="profile"]').tab('show')` :) I don't have any anchor-tags but divs (as in the original example)... it's strange that they use `a` in the example of the JS and `divs` in the example for the html

Comment: Great job, I'm glad it works! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 replace `data-bs-toggle` `data-bs-target` to `data-toggle` `data-target` respectively.